# Wordpress form input css displaying differently in Firefox and Chrome

Tags: css, wordpress

I am trying to code an email opt-in box, I have a theme already installed and am using Wordpress. The box looks as it should in Firefox, but displays incorrectly in Chrome, including no padding in the text fields, font color different in text field, a 2px-ish padding that shouldn't be above and below the blue submit button.

Including `!important` has no effect.

The website is http://shannonconfairphotography.com, the box is at the top of the page, and displays great in firefox. Normally I don't see any difference between Chrome and Firefox, only IE, so I'm stumped.

The box code is:

```
<div style="background-color:#efefef; padding:0; margin:0; -webkit-box-sizing:content-box !important; -moz-box-sizing:content-box !important; box-sizing:content-box !important;">
<span style="font-family: 'Rouge Script', cursive; font-size:30px; line-height:16px; color:#8e8e8e; margin-right:15px; padding-left:15px;"> 5 easy ways to save money on your wedding...</span>
 <form style="display:inline; margin:0px; padding:0px; height:100%;" action="https://madmimi.com/signups/" method="post" target="_blank"> 
    <input style="display:inline; margin:0px; font-family: 'Rouge Script', cursive; font-size:28px; line-height:22px; height:40px; border:none; color:#acacac; background-color:#fff; width:200px; padding-left:10px; margin-right:5px;" id="signup_first_name" name="signup[first_name]" type="text" placeholder="first name">
    <input style="display:inline; margin:0px; font-family: 'Rouge Script', cursive; font-size:28px; line-height:22px; height:40px; border:none; color:#acacac; background-color:#fff; width:200px; padding-left:10px; margin-right:11px;" name="signup[email]" type="text" placeholder="email"> 
    <input style="background-image:none; border: none; background-color:#023972; color:#fff; font-family: 'Rouge Script', cursive; font-size:28px; padding:10px;" value="get it!" type="submit" class="submit"> 
  </form>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the `line-height: 22px;` line from the `<input>` style seems to correct the positioning of the text.

Try using `::-webkit-input-placeholder { color: [your color]; }` to change the color of the input placeholder text in Chrome.

Comment: Thanks! I don't suppose you know why there is about a 2px margin around the blue button in Chrome but not in Firefox (I don't want the extra space). Also, I can't seem to override the existing themes css for text input color. Maybe the !important isn't working because I'm not using a seperate css file, but putting it all under style=".." instead of class=".."? Thanks again.

Comment: Oh, and I'd vote you up but I have no reputation (just like irl), lol ;)

Comment: Not sure what creates the margin, but if you set margin: 0; it gets rid of it. There are a lot of stylesheets called in your theme, so kinda hard to pin down a conflict with `::-webkit-input-placeholder { color: [your color]; }`. Try adding this into the HTML: `<style type="text/css"> ::-webkit-input-placeholder { color: #ddd; } input { margin: 0; } </style>`

Comment: Wow, and again thanks. Everything is fixed! Quick question if I may (and I'm not embarrassed to say that after 6 years of designing sites, css still confuses me): Why did your input {margin: 0;} fix the issue when I had  <input style="margin:0; .."? Thanks again, I really appreciate your taking the time to help :)

Comment: Hm, hard to say -- I actually don't have much experience with `<input>` fields and inline CSS, so not sure what the issue might've been. But glad to have helped :)